# django list_display and get_absolute_url

Tags: django, django-admin

Inside admin I want the `list_display` of a model to include the `get_absolute_url` and be clickable. Currently it just shows `/x/` (x being the ID). Any quick fixes?

Model:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):  
    return "/%i/" % self.id
```

Admin:

```
list_display = ('name', 'get_absolute_url')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'show_link')

    def show_link(self, obj):
        return '<a href="%s">Click here</a>' % obj.get_absolute_url()
    show_link.allow_tags = True
```